# Cassandra - Dev center not able to connect to all the 3 nodes of Cassandra cluster

Tags: amazon-ec2, cassandra, datastax, cassandra-3.0

I'm new to Cassandra and EC2 configuration.

I have configured 3 nodes in AWS EC2 instances with Cassandra 3.0 and all the three nodes are connected to each other .

Following things have been configured in .yaml fie.

Broadcast_add: Private ip ec2 add of instance
seeds : public ip add of all the three nodes.
rpc_add : blank

When I try to connect to this cluster from Datastax dev centre it shows only connected to one node. When individually connecting to all the 3 ip's it gets connected to all the nodes. But when connecting to cluster with 3 ip's in connection file, it connects to only one node.

Could any one help with this issue ?

Thanks
Uttkarsh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
open cassandra.yaml file and change the

1) listen_address        :-   private IP
2) broadcast_address     :-   blank
3) listen_on_broadcast_address:- true
4) rpc_address           :-   0.0.0.0
5) broadcast_rpc_address :-   public IP
6) seeds ip              :-   public IP for node.    

it's working finally


Thanks Utpal
```